# Pandas: Get out values from a list in a DataFrame

Tags: python, list, pandas

from one of my scripts I end up with a big dataframe in Pandas
and one of it's columns look like this

```
13      [1705916]
14    [116242799]
15     [17865718]
...
9551      [74736013]
9553              []
9620      [92090990]
9666        [113455]
9667     [327478610]
9733      [52782791]
9838              []
9951     [229462842]
9952              []
10070             []
```

When I do type(df.column_of_interest)
I get back `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>.`

So my question is, is it possible to extract data from list in a dataframe while keeping rows with empty values in the list?

expected output:

```
13      1705916
14    116242799
15     17865718
...
9551      74736013
9553              
9620      92090990
9666        113455
9667     327478610
9733      52782791
9838              
9951     229462842
9952              
10070
```

Comment: what do you want to do if there are multiple values in a list?

Comment: And what type do you want that column at the end, if a numerical type, you cannot have empty , it should become `NaN` then.

Comment: If there is multiple values would be great if it is outputed as values separated by comma
something like: 15       15566, 5465456, 555563
Nan values for empty cells is perfect as well

Comment: So you want string as output?

Comment: yes a string is perfect

Comment: And are they currently string or are they ints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column is currently a list of integers, then you can use `series.apply` along with `str.join()` to get what you want. Example -

```
In [42]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,[2]],[2,[3]],[3,[]],[4,[5,6]]], columns=['A','B'])

In [43]: df
Out[43]:
   A       B
0  1     [2]
1  2     [3]
2  3      []
3  4  [5, 6]

In [44]: df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x:','.join([str(i) for i in x]))

In [45]: df
Out[45]:
   A    B
0  1    2
1  2    3
2  3
3  4  5,6
```

Comment: Perfect , thanks 
I was looking the wrong way by using things like  itertools.chain but it was removing empty values.